# OAuth Connected App without Identity Provider Enabled

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

Working on a project where the client wants to be able to use OAuth to login to an external website backend.  The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=quickstart_oauth.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/quickstart_oauth.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) for setting up OAuth doesn't actually mention enabling the IDP so I'm wondering if it is a requirement to use oAuth?

My concern is they currently don't have custom domain enabled (requirement for IDP), and doing so is likely to cause issues across their org (static links in email templates, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, setting up an identity provider isn't necessary to use an oauth connected app.  Just create your connected app and use the supplied client id/secret to handle the login.